# Regex for replacing all whitespaces to tab characters at the beginning of each line

Tags: javascript, regex, tabs, removing-whitespace

I want to replace all 2 white space characters with one tab character (\t) at the beginning of each line.
As shown in the example below, white spaces between non-white space (comment line) should not be replaced.

I want to convert this:

```
int main() {
  if (true)
    cout << "Hi";  // comment
}
```

to this:

```
int main() {
\tif (true)
\t\tcout << "Hi";  // comment
}
```

This regex I come up with catches only one whitespace pair per line:

```
^(\s\s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for all leading spaces and use a callback to compute the length of the replacement

```js
src = `
int main() {
  if (true)
    cout << "Hi";  // comment
}
`

tabs = src.replace(/^ +/gm, s => '\t'.repeat(s.length / 2))

console.log(tabs)
```